# Let $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ For what values of $x$ is $F'(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ For what values of $x$ is $F'(x)=f(x)$?

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\leq1\\
1 & x>1
\end{cases}$

I know by the fundamental theorem of the calculus

$F'(x)=f(x)$, Now, Where $F'(x)=f(x)$?

Well, i was think, $F'(x)=f(x) \forall x\epsilon\left[0,\infty\right]$ I think this, for the limits of integrations of F(x). But I'm not sure, could they help me?

Comment: Doesn't the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus impose some conditions on $f$?

Comment: The (Riemann) fundamental theorem of calculus requires $f$ to be continuous. This $f$ is not continuous. So there is some question about where $F'=f$. On the other hand, in this case you can explicitly calculate $F$ in order to check where it is differentiable and to compute its derivative where that derivative exists.

Comment: You could try considering what $F'(1)$ might mean here

Answer (score 1):

For $x\le1$, $\displaystyle F(x)=0$.

For $x>1$, 
$$F(x)=\int_1^xdt=x-1$$

So for $x<1$, $F'(x)=0=f(x)$.

For $x>1$, $F'(x)=1=f(x)$.

$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{F(1+h)-F(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{F(1+h)-F(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{1+h-1-0}{h}=1$$

$F$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.

$F'(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$.